# Replacement of special characters such as dolar and parentheses signs inside sparql query while we use python code

Tags: python, sparql

I am trying to make some queries by which I can find strings such as x containing substrings such as $y). Then I want to replace these substrings with $z). I tried many ways such as the following codes but I faced with errors. The problem is related to REPLACE function the signs '$', '(' and ')' are special characters. Some of my attempts are: (Here pref_old_iri and pref_new_iri are some prefixed form of IRIs)

```
    old = '$' + pref_old_iri + ')'
    new = '$' + pref_new_iri + ')'

    model.update(f"""
    DELETE{{?x ?p ?y .}}
    INSERT{{?z ?p ?y .}}
    WHERE{{
        ?x ?p ?y .
        FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?x), "{old}"))
        BIND(IRI(REPLACE(STR(?x), "{old}", "{new}")) AS ?z)
    }} """)
```

or

```
    old = '$' + pref_old_iri + ')'
    new = '$' + pref_new_iri + ')'

    model.update(f"""
    DELETE{{?x ?p ?y .}}
    INSERT{{?z ?p ?y .}}
    WHERE{{
        ?x ?p ?y .
        FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?x), "{old}"))
        BIND(IRI(REPLACE(STR(?x), '\$'+"{pref_old_iri}"+'\)', '\$'+"{pref_new_iri}"+'\)')) AS ?z)
    }} """)
```

I should mention that it is necessary for me to replace such strings concated with signs '$' and  ')', since it may happen that pref_old_iri is occured in x without these two signs and so it souldn't be replaced. Moreover, it is important that I am using fstrings and usage of "\ \$" for scaping this special character dose not work.

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: can't you simply escape the special chars with `\\$` and `\\)`?

Comment: `SELECT * WHERE {
  VALUES ?s {"some$test)" "sometest"}
  BIND(REPLACE(STR(?s), "\\$test\\)", "\\$test_new\\)") AS ?z)
}` works for me

Comment: I need working with fstrings. pref_old_iri and pref_new_iri are variables. I tried \\ but it seems this does not work for fstrings.